# How to specify that a view should take up the rest available space?

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard, space, iphone-5

I'm targeting iPhone 4 and iPhone 5, so I want my view to take as much available space as possible. For example, I want the the table view to take the remaining space according to iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 screen.

[image]

Is there any option (Storyboard or code) so that I can do this? Like `Height="*"` in XAML or `weight` in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enale autolayout like this

[image]

& write below code

```
self.tableView.autoResizingMasks=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
```

Comment: After enabling Use Autolayout, I put that code in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, but it does not work

Comment: self.view.autoResizingMasks=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

Comment: Sorry, I thought that Autolayout does not work with Autoresizing ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use Auto-layout. Here is a tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2